# what's called after returning from presentModalViewController / dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

to show a modal uiview out of my mainView I use:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

and in MyController I close that view with:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But how can I know in the mainView that the modal was finished (to redraw my table)?
Currently I set a local variable to YES in my mainView after starting the modal view an react on viewWillAppear:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myController animated:YES];
_reloadTableData = YES;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   if (_reloadTableData) {
     _reloadTableData = NO;
     [_tableView reloadData];
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to do so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's not appropriate to dismiss the modal view by the modal view itself.

Instead, you should set your **main view** as the delegate of the modal view. When you modal view finishes its task, it can let its delegate know and let its delegate dismiss it. This is the very common so-called delegate design pattern in Objective-C.

btw, you may want to consult with some code samples to gain a better understanding of this delegate pattern. I suggest you take a look at one of Xcode's default templates - the **Utility Application** template. It has a very succinct and simple and straightforward delegate structure built inside.

Comment: @middaparka: cannot agree more :-)

Comment: diwup thank you. now my code looks much familiar to the other one.