# progress bar downloading image

Tags: iphone, progress-bar

In my application i want to show the size of downloading image in label.like, 5 KB of 2MB .

Progress bar is used to show the image downloading and i want to show the total size of [image]currently downloading image as well as completed size of downloading(like,5 KB of 2 MB)

Anyone give me guidance to do this.

For this What should i do.please give me any sample code or tutorial for this.

**Added Informations:**

Already i'm using ASIHTTP Library .There are several delegate methods.In which method i want to give the code for finding the total size of the download image and progress of the downloding image.Please give me a code for findout the size of both (total size and downloaded size ) of an image.Please help me .stil i have no idea to find the size and which delegate method is used to support.

**I'm really struggle in this.Please any one guide me to do this.**

Comment: I'm interested to know as well.   The tricky thing is knowing the progress of the download, since most of the built-in APIs suck down entire resources at a time and don't offer "progress" delegate callbacks.   You could always do it yourself by downloading the image in chunks, but what APIs are available that allow that?

Comment: I just added an answer to give you a few hints to start with.

Comment: As of my knowledge, if you set `UIProgressView` as `downloadProgressDelegate`, then it will only updtae `UIProgressView`, and `- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes;` will never call, to call this method you need to set, `downloadProgressDelegate` to `self`. Let me know if I'm wrong. Or put your answer if you able to update label and progressview at the same time? Any hint will be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need some **real** code to start with, here are a few hints.

- Drag and drop the **ASIHTTPRequest** package into your project.
- Since what you want is download images from the internet, you only need to deal with one class in the ASI package, the **ASIHTTPRequest** class.
- Read the **ASIHTTPRequest.h** file closely before you start. It has every interface you need.
- Specifically, pay attention to these two methods, you will have to override them to get real-time download statistics.

.

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request incrementDownloadSizeBy:(long long)newLength;
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes;
```

Comment: now i'm able to find the total bytes and downloaded bytes.but how can i get the value to label(label is in some otherview)please help me

Comment: You new questions is related to communication between different view controllers. Take a look at this post, it is not directly relevant to your question, but it may point you to the right direction, which is, the **Delegate Design Pattern** in Objective-C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578608/whats-called-after-returning-from-presentmodalviewcontroller-dismissmodalviewc/

Comment: How does one 'override' those 2 methods? Should they be defined in my viewcontroller? What would I set the `setDownloadProgressDelegate:` to?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your own download progress system, or a simpler alternative that avoids reinventing the wheel would be to use the excellent *ASIHTTPRequest* library that provides you with a delegate method for getting the progress of a current download. It's also rather well documented: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: @diwup:which one is worked perfectly for your project.could you please give me a guidance in this regard.Thank you

Comment: @Ixt:Please help me how can i get the progress message while downloading the image using ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete tutorial for building iPhone app downloading images from internet:

In part 2 there's the mechanics of having a progress bar, just download the sample project.

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/update-your-iphone-app-with-new-content-part-2/

Comment: The sample project you have given to me doesn't have any progress message along with the progressbar.And i have done my application using ASIHTTPRequest Library for downloading image with progressbar.Now i want to simply add the progress message of downloading the image in label(like,5 KB of 3 MB)

Comment: What's the exact problem you are having? You don't know how to add the label to the UI or you don't know how to track the progress of the download? You can always read the ASIHTTPRequest manual if you don't know how to track the progress of the download : http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: Zlib:I don't know how to track the progress of the downloading the image.